# Fetch JSON object from GAS WebApp from another development GAS WebApp?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, urlfetch

I have two different GAS projects Script1 and Script2.

**Script1:**
It is a development project with `doPost()` function. It uses the `e.parameter` or `e.postData.contents` to do something.

**Script2:**
It is a test script. It has also `doPost()` function. I want to transfer the `doPost()` `e.parameter` to Script1 by a post request. But the URLFetchApp success when I use the **Current web app URL** and ends in `/exec`. But I want to use the **latest code** and ends in `/dev`. Because of the Script1 is a development project and I can't update its version for a small change.

I tried this code. It not working

```
function myFunction() {
  //var URL = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/exec";
  var URL = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/dev";
  var data = {
      'message' : "This is working"
    }
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL, options);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to access to Web Apps with the dev mode using Google Apps Script.

For this, How about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- In order to access to the Web Apps with the dev mode, please use the access token. And in this sample, the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` is used for the access token.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

```
function myFunction() {
  //var URL = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/exec";
  var URL = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/dev";
  var data = {
      'message' : "This is working"
    }
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(data),
    'headers': {'authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()} // Added
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL, options);
}

// DriveApp.getFiles()  // Added
```

#### Note:

- The comment line of `// DriveApp.getFiles()` is used for automatically detecting the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` by the script editor.
- When the access token is used, even when `Who has access to the app:` is `Only myself`, the script works.

#### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: But how can I call when `Who has access to the app:` is `Only myself`? Which GAS wat set `Who has access to the app:` is `Only myself`? `/dev` app or `/exec` app?

Comment: @e-lab innovations Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. In the case of `Who has access to the app: Only myself`, the URL is `/exec`. In your case that the URL of `/dev` is used, above script can be also used. But in this case, it supposes that the script of Web Apps worked. If the script of Web Apps occurs an error, the error is returned. Please be careful this.